# Orchard CMS Editable Content on MVC Views

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I'm working on an Orchard module for selling an e-book of sorts. Prior to purchase, a user can view a page showing a sample of the product. After purchase, there is no more need for the sample page, and the user has access to the full product.

I would like to set things up such that if a paying customer tries to access the sample page that they would be redirected to their full product and if a non-customer were to try to go to full product page they would be redirected to the sample. I'd also like my page content to be editable via the Dashboard.

My current implementation:

- Controller handling the conditional routing / redirecting based on whether a purchase has been made.
- A layer rule for each of my page url's each containing an html widget to provide the page content

This seems to work, but I am wondering what other options I have to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be making things way more complicated than they need to be.

Using widgets is unnecessary. It would be much better to build a regular content type and display that. You could serve it through a special controller that checks for a purchase, but even that is unnecessary. Instead, you could create a part that would have the purchase verification logic in its driver's display method. This way, you could even apply the exact same logic to any content type.

Comment: If I were to include my logic in a part driver can I do page redirects or do you mean only my display shape would change but on the same route?

Comment: Sure: write an implementation of DriverResult that does the redirect from its Apply method, and return an instance of that from the driver.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. Your answer to my original question helped me figure out a way to do this using the part driver without the need for redirects afterall.